# What is the Difference Between UX and UI?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

What is the difference between user Interface and user experience? or simple Difference between  UI and UX?
Can I say UI is a way to  achieve UX?

Answer (score 1):

They are very close ... in my opinion, the UX corresponds more to technical aspects or structure. The UX designer will use evaluation techniques such as Heuristic evaluation, Usability testing, Eye tracking, A / B testing, etc.
By these process, the UX designer is closer to cognitive science (many are pschologist).

The UI refers more to the appearance of an interface, to its design. In my opinion, it is a question of interpreting the results obtained during UX tests to put them in image (and maybe to test them again).
Designers are clearly confronted with UI issues.

It is assumed that the work of UX is done before the work of UI (it can also be done at the same time). Some process, like Wireframing, can concern both a UX and a UI designer.

Of course, my analysis is very general ...

Comment: Thanks for this answer.But can you explain  with the help of any example?

Answer (score 0):

**UX** -focuses on the journey that the user takes and how the product is structured to facilitate this journey. It involves understanding the user needs and translating
them into meaningful user interactions. Most tasks in UX deal with research, conducting user surveys, interviews, creating user journeys, maps among many others.

**UI** -focus is on how users immediately decide whether they’d like to engage with a product or not. Before UX even comes into question, users judge a system based on its appearance. UI communicates identity and branding to the users while translating the different research and interactions into meaningful designs, i.e. interface layout, visual design, interaction design and establishing visual guidelines.